# Is there a native HTTP response caching facility / step in Microsoft Power Automate?

Tags: power-automate

I'm using Power Automate to build an API in front of an ETL process, but am finding that the performance of this product is ***nightmarishly slow and unpredictable***.

This process receives an HTTP request with some parameters, reads and converts some rows from an Excel file hosted in Sharepoint to JSON and sends a response.

[image]

Example request:

```
{{ url }}?id_to_fetch=ABC123
```

Example response

```
{ records: ["X", "Y", "Z"] }
```

I would like to avoid the overhead of setting up a full-blown CDN in front of what should be an extraordinarily simple operation.

Is there any way to serve a cached response from a Power Automate pipeline without adding any other non-free products to the mix?

Comment: You have two loops, that’s going to cause overhead. Which steps are taking the longest? If it’s the loops, how many items is it iterating through? What steps are inside the foreach’s?

Comment: The entire process is literally reading 3 - 4 rows from each loop and appending them to an array.  If this were a normal programming language, we'd be talking nanoseconds of processing.  I'm mainly confused about why some invocations take 2-3 seconds and some take 40 seconds.  It's the same input, processing the same data, and returning the same output.

Comment: Ok so what’s taking the longest?

Comment: After reaching out to various colleagues, others have seen very similar performance with Power Automate.  I was unable/unwilling to allocate any more hours to debugging this.  Spent 30 minutes porting the project over to a lambda+S3 based solution on AWS and it consistently runs well within my tolerance threshold.

Comment: Yeah, the PA/LA platform has additional layers and it will never run as fast as code level projects that you develop on AWS/Azure.  That's well documented and, to be honest, it should be expected.  Also, using it for a HTTP endpoint is a little dangerous if you expect a synchronous response and I think you've learnt that.  But for other event based triggers that can run asynchronously, it's brilliant.  Still keen to understand where the bottle neck was but whatever.